# Javascript error event using meteor starter files

Tags: javascript, node.js, events, meteor, eof

I'm building an app that uses the Meteor starter files and sometimes get this error which I think is related to Node.js:

the error is:
events.js:72
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event

Error: write EOF
at errnoException (net.js:905:11)
at Object.afterWrite (net.js:721:19)

I wanted to check if anyone has ever come across it before and if you have and recommendations on how to fix it?

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: It seems you have a problem with your code. However, we can't help unless we have [code or information that can reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise, we are just blindly guessing.

Comment: I have the same issue here - and the same code is working fine on my colleague's machine, so I guess this must be in internal meteor issue - were you able to solve this?

Comment: PS: The error is thrown directly after MongoDB is stared:
=> Started proxy.
=> Started MongoDB.
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event